# Firebase deploy get ID with onCreate for push notifications

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating an iOS app and sending notifications. I'm trying to get an id from Firebase but the code below doesn't work.

```
exports.pushNotifications = functions.database.ref('/message/{messageId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

var messageId = event.params.uid;

.
.
.
```

I tried this code from the documentation `"const pathId = context.params.id"` but I can't get anything.

How do you get the id created by `childByAutoId()` in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve the id:

```
exports.arrivalNotifications = functions.database.ref('/message/{messageId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

var messageId = context.params.messageId;

});
```

It needs to be the same name as inside the wildcard `{}`

Comment: Thank you! I should've noticed earlier.